# Flutter Provider rebuild widget on page intent

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

i just learn about provider,and make a demo.i have A,B 2 page,and A page user consumer to use model's value. A page have a button,and click it can open Page B,when it intent to B page,A page's cusomer rebuild,and back to A page,it also made A page's consumer rebuild.what's wrong with it? any one can help me? thanks. i have search many articles,but no one about it.
there are my code.

model

```
class PageModel with ChangeNotifier {

  int _count = 0;

  void addCount() {
    _count += 5;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int get count => _count;

}
```

main

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType = null;

      return MyHomePage();
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_)=> PageModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
      home: ProviderPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

A page

```
class ProviderPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('ProviderPage create');
  }

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ProviderPageState();
  }

}
class ProviderPageState extends State<ProviderPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('initState');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Consumer<PageModel>(builder: (context, data, _) {
              print('ProviderPage Text ${data.count}');
              return Text('${data.count}');
            }),
//              Text('${Provider.of<PageModel>(context).count}'),
            Builder(builder: (_) {
              print('builder RaisedButton');
              return RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
                Provider.of<PageModel>(context, listen: false).addCount();
              }, child: Text('+5'),);
            }),
            RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return ProviderPage1();
                    }
                ),);
            }, child: Text('intent'),)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    print('didChangeDependencies');
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(ProviderPage oldWidget) {
    print('didUpdateWidget');
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

}
```

B page

```
class ProviderPage1 extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('B create');
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
//              Consumer<PageModel>(builder: (context,data,_) {
//                print('ProviderPage1 Text');
//                return Text('${data.count}');
//              }),
//              Text('${Provider.of<PageModel>(context).count}'),
//              Builder(builder: (_){
//                print('builder RaisedButton1');
//                return RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
//                  Provider.of<PageModel>(context,listen: false).addCount();
//                },child: Text('+5'),);
//              }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reference 
Pages on Navigator stack rebuild when a new page is pushed https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11655

Flutter team's reply 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11655#issuecomment-348287396 
This is working as intended. In general, you should assume that all widgets can rebuild at any time, that they don't is mostly just an optimisation.

In particular, routes will rebuild because their navigator state has changed so they might need to update how they draw back buttons and the like.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11655#issuecomment-412413030 
You should generally assume that every widget will be rebuild every frame, and design your build methods to be idempotent (i.e. running them multiple times should do nothing different than running them once), and fast (so that there's no problem with running them a lot). In practice we run build methods less often than that but you shouldn't rely on that.